# How can I duplicate a section of a JSON file within that file using Python?

Tags: python, json

Is there any way to duplicate a part of a JSON file within the same file using Python? I would like to take the `Changelog` part of my file and duplicate elements of the 'views' section *within* the 'views' section.

Here's the code I want to duplicate:

```
{
  "title": "1.0",
  "useBoldText": true,
  "useBottomMargin": true,
  "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
},
{
  "markdown": "\t\n\u2022 Initial Release",
  "useSpacing": false,
  "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
},
{
  "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 3/7/2019</small>",
  "useRawFormat": true,
  "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
}
```

JSON File:

```
{
  "minVersion": "0.1",
  "headerImage": "",
  "tintColor": "",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "tabname": "Changelog",
      "views": [
        {
          "title": "1.0",
          "useBoldText": true,
          "useBottomMargin": true,
          "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "\t\n\u2022 Initial Release",
          "useSpacing": false,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 3/7/2019</small>",
          "useRawFormat": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        }
      ],
      "class": "DepictionStackView"
    }
  ],
  "class": "DepictionTabView"
}
```

It should look like this when done:

```
{
  "minVersion": "0.1",
  "headerImage": "",
  "tintColor": "",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "tabname": "Changelog",
      "views": [

      {
        "title": "1.1",
        "useBoldText": true,
        "useBottomMargin": true,
        "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
      },
      {
        "markdown": "\t\n\u2022 Some More Changes",
        "useSpacing": false,
        "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
      },
      {
        "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 3/7/19</small>",
        "useRawFormat": true,
        "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
      }
     ],

        {
          "title": "1.0",
          "useBoldText": true,
          "useBottomMargin": true,
          "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "\t\n\u2022 Initial Release",
          "useSpacing": false,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 3/1/2019</small>",
          "useRawFormat": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        }
      ],

      "class": "DepictionStackView"
    }
  ],
  "class": "DepictionTabView"
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you'd like the results to look like? the 'views' key contains three different elements at the moment. Are your saying you'd like to add three more identical to those to the views section?

Comment: Or that you'd like to add another tab to the tabs section, like 'Changelog 2'?

Comment: @Chris Larson I updated the post with what I want it to look like.

Comment: @Brian, what you want to get is not even valid JSON

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't going to work as JSON. You need to create a new entry with another 'tabname' for it to be valid JSON.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know if that's along the lines you're looking for?

Comment: It seems to work in a IOS Cydia alt called Sileo for native depictions to display changes/version history. developer.getsileo.app/native-depictions twitter.com/getsileo?lang=en @Chris Larson

Comment: Example: https://github.com/BrianLeek/repo/blob/3a11af404034f69119704f412e5d76fe833b0660/packageInfo/native-depictions/brianleek.github.cleanclockanddate-native#L100

Answer (score 0):

You read your JSON file, take the part you need, and put what you want at the beginning of the file. Let's say your file is called `data.json`:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    required_data = data["tabs"][0]["views"]
    f.seek(0, 0)
    f.write(str(required_data) + '\n' + str(data))
```

Comment: I get a error: required_data = data["tabs"]["views"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Brian, I edited my answer to remove the error you were having, but I want to insist that what you want to achieve is not valid JSON, so could you please update your output.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will open your JSON file and read the JSON structure into the variable `data`.

It will then create a duplicate of the `list.copy(data['tabs'][0]['views'])` structure (`data['tabs'][0]['views']` refers to the 'views' section of index 0 of the group, or `list` in python terms, in the 'tabs' section), which in this case is the structure you're targeting, as the variable `new_tab`.

Next, it'll add a space and the word 'copy' to the `value` of either the 'title' or the 'markdown' `key` of each view, depending on which one exists, in `new_tab` (the copy).

Then it'll add `new_tab` to the existing JSON structure.

Finally, it will write the updated JSON structure to the original file.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as copying:
    data = json.load(copying)

new_tab = list.copy(data['tabs'][0]['views'])

for view in new_tab:
    if 'title' in view.keys():
        view['title'] = f"{view['title']} copy"
    elif 'markdown' in view.keys():
        view['markdown'] = f"{view['markdown']} copy"

data['tabs'][0]['views'].extend(new_tab)

with open(filename, 'w') as copying:
    json.dump(data, copying)
```

The output will be a file that looks like this:

```
{
    "minVersion": "0.1",
    "headerImage": "",
    "tintColor": "",
    "tabs": [
        {
            "tabname": "Changelog",
            "views": [
                {
                    "title": "1.0 copy",
                    "useBoldText": true,
                    "useBottomMargin": true,
                    "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
                },
                {
                    "markdown": "\t\n• Initial Release copy",
                    "useSpacing": false,
                    "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
                },
                {
                    "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 3/7/2019</small> copy",
                    "useRawFormat": true,
                    "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
                },
                {
                    "title": "1.0 copy",
                    "useBoldText": true,
                    "useBottomMargin": true,
                    "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
                },
                {
                    "markdown": "\t\n• Initial Release copy",
                    "useSpacing": false,
                    "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
                },
                {
                    "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 3/7/2019</small> copy",
                    "useRawFormat": true,
                    "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
                }
            ],
            "class": "DepictionStackView"
        }
    ],
    "class": "DepictionTabView"
}
```

On a side note, whenever you're working with JSON, it's a good idea to test your structure. There's a great resource for doing this at [JSONLint - The JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/) Simply copy your JSON structure, paste it in there, and click the 'Validate JSON' button.

Comment: I want to keep it all in the same Changelog code you see in my post if you look at what it should look like when done but thanks.

Comment: You understand that will break the json? And any software that uses the JSON?

Comment: It seems to work in a IOS Cydia alt called Sileo for native depictions to display changes/version history. https://developer.getsileo.app/native-depictions https://twitter.com/getsileo?lang=en

Comment: Example: https://github.com/BrianLeek/repo/blob/3a11af404034f69119704f412e5d76fe833b0660/packageInfo/native-depictions/brianleek.github.cleanclockanddate-native#L100 @Chris Larson

Comment: Ah! I see. Though notice that yhour example of the finished product isn't simply a duplicate, but has different values. It's not just a 'copy/paste'. My answer is what you're looking for, but you wan't to adjust the elements I've copied to be within the 'views' structure, and you'll want to change the values before adding them. I'll see if I have a moment to adjust the answer. If you just duplicate them exactly, you'll have problems with your goal.

Comment: Oh, and you want to stay inside the closing `]`, Compare your copy/paste to the sileo example at https://repo.dynastic.co/sileo-depiction/68292503631036416/, and you'll see the brackets are important as ending the whole list. Use the link at the bottom of my answer to paste the sileo code in and have it validated and prettyprinted.

Comment: And there you go. As I understand what you're looking to do, the updated answer should be exactly what you're looking for. You'll want to play around with the code and extend it for the content you want in each 'view' element, but this should provide the tools you need to understand and address the issue. Thanks for introducing me to the Sileo stuff. I'll take a look at that. And again, JSONLint will be your best friend here! ::grin:: Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but sorry but this messes up my code see and adds the word 'copy' in random places it doesn't even add more changelog info like in the example this is what the code looks like https://pastebin.com/dytVTKUf also my scripts takes user input and changes the placeholder text in the template file and save it as a new file you can find the code at https://github.com/BrianLeek/Sileo-Native-Depiction-Generator

Comment: I didn't intend to create a tool for you, and that's not really what StackOverflow is for. StackOverflow is for asking and getting answers regarding technical approaches to a problem. As a programmer, the tools in my answer are a framework for you to understand the problem, think through your own needs and create your own solution. :) I have no idea what your own code looks like or is intended to do, and therefore cannot create your actual tool.

Comment: I am a professional programmer, and do this for a living, so if you'd like to take this off StackOverflow and pay me to create a solution for you, I'm happy to consider that, but what you're currently asking for isn't what this place is for.

Comment: Please don't read my comments as meant harshly. I was happy to put the time into creating the answer, and I'm responding with respect and to gently correct what may be a misunderstanding of StackOverflow.

Comment: Specific comments: The word 'copy' was put in as an example of changing the text of an element to whatever you wish it to be. Taking user input is a different question, but has many answers on SO. You should be able to easily take the code in my answer, alter it to take user input, and use that instead of the copied text I used in my example. Also, using the last bit that saves the file should illustrate how to 'save it as a new file' by simply changing `filename`. The same applies to 'add more changelog info like in the example'. The tools you need are there in the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Oh ok @Chris Larson thanks for your help i don't have to much experience with Python thats why I am looking for a exact answer but I understand and I will see if I can get this to work.

Comment: You're welcome! This is a great project for learning Python. Just think through each thing you need the code to do. Basically, it sounds like you want a user to add a new entry to the Changelog, right? So you want to create `dict`s that hold the bits for the 'title' and the 'markdown' entries the user adds, then put them into the `new_tab`, and then add that the `data` dict. Then just save the file however you want with the `filename`. You'll want to check out using `dict`s and `input`, but you'll figure it out really quickly! Good luck!

Comment: And if you get stuck on a specific thing, that **is** what StackOverflow is for! Don't hesitate to ask those here. Oh, and one other option wiould be to create a smaller JSON file with just your new Changelog entry, then read that file in with `json.load()` and simply add that to the `data` dict. That might be your absolute best approach.